# Xcode and ios simulator crash on startup/launch

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator

Log:

```
Process:               Xcode [1468]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               9.0 (13247)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-13247000000000000~26
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1468]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-09-26 11:35:39.310 +0545
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        52819ED3-E50E-349A-8094-46E97C49AE09


Time Awake Since Boot: 1900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/XcodeKit.framework/Versions/A/XcodeKit
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x10252d000 -        0x10252eff7  com.apple.dt.Xcode (9.0 - 13247) <B228B806-ACF1-31C6-8881-6F0ED5AD58B3> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       ...
       ...
       ...
       ...
    0x7fffac0b0000 -     0x7fffac0b5ffb  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <3D50D8A8-C460-334D-A519-2DA841102C6B> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fffac0b6000 -     0x7fffac0dfff7  libxpc.dylib (972.70.1) <BF896DF0-D8E9-31A8-A4B3-01120BFEEE52> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B22, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343235533641465236412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343235533641465236412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.130.1a1)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.5f1, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS545050A7E362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS41N
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: SAMSUNG_Android
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Comment: I have downloaded xcode again and it is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a corrupt install of Xcode. Have you tried deleting it and re-downloading?

Comment: Yes, re-downloading it helped